# How to implement template class covariance in C++?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, covariance, contravariance

Is it possible to implement a class template in such a way that one object could be casted to another if their template arguments are related? Here is an exaple to show the idea (of course it will not compile):

```
struct Base {};
struct Derived : Base {};

template <typename T> class Foo {
    virtual ~Foo() {}
    virtual T* some_function() = 0;
};

Foo<Derived>* derived = ...;
Foo<Base>* base = derived;
```

The additional problem here is that Foo is an abstract class used as an interface containing functions returning T& and T*, so I can't implement a template copy constructor.

I'm writing a universal Iterator class which can hold any STL iterator, and in addition to type erasure I'd like it to be polymorphic, i.e. I could write something like this:

```
std::list<Derived> l;
MyIterator<Base> it(l.begin());
```

UPD: That was my mistake, I didn't actually need casting Foo* to Foo* to implement MyIterator, so I think the question is not actual anymore.

Comment: I very much doubt `dynamic_cast` will do what you want here.

Comment: Oops! You're right, it's returning NULL :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The template argument has nothing to do with the content of the object you are pointing to. There is no reason this should work. To illustrate

```
struct Base { };
struct Derived : Base {};

template<typename T> struct A { int foo; };
template<> struct A<Base> { int foo; int bar; };

A<Derived> a;
A<Base> *b = &a; // assume this would work
b->bar = 0; // oops!
```

You will eventually access integer `bar` that doesn't really exist in `a`!

---

OK, now that you provided some more information, it's clear you want to do something completely different. Here is some starter:

```
template<typename T>
struct MyIterator : std::iterator<...> {
  MyIterator():ibase() { }
  template<typename U>
  MyIterator(U u):ibase(new Impl<U>(u)) { }
  MyIterator(MyIterator const& a):ibase(a.ibase->clone())

  MyIterator &operator=(MyIterator m) {
    m.ibase.swap(ibase);
    return *this;
  }

  MyIterator &operator++() { ibase->inc(); return *this; }
  MyIterator &operator--() { ibase->dec(); return *this; }
  T &operator*() { return ibase->deref(); }
  // ...

private:
  struct IBase { 
    virtual ~IBase() { }
    virtual T &deref() = 0; 
    virtual void inc() = 0;
    virtual void dec() = 0;
    // ...

    virtual IBase *clone() = 0;
  };
  template<typename U>
  struct Impl : IBase { 
    Impl(U u):u(u) { }
    virtual T &deref() { return *u; }
    virtual void inc() { ++u; }
    virtual void dec() { --u; }
    virtual IBase *clone() { return new Impl(*this); }
    U u;
  };

  boost::scoped_ptr<IBase> ibase;
};
```

Then you can use it as

```
MyIterator<Base> it(l.begin());
++it; 
Base &b = *it;
```

You may want to look into [`any_iterator`](http://thbecker.net/free_software_utilities/type_erasure_for_cpp_iterators/any_iterator.html). With a bit of luck, you can use that template for your purpose (I haven't tested it).

Comment: Oh, so simple! I've written almost exactly the same code, but with IBase and Impl as global classes (not nested) - this was I mistake that made me stuck, because Impl was inheriting from Ibase<typename std::iterator_traits<U>::value_type>, which was different from T, so the pointers were not covariant. Now I've put them inside MyIterator and everything works :)

Comment: Any ideas on how to implement `MyIterator`'s `operator==` for cases like when one is `MyIterator<int>::Impl<std::vector<int>::const_iterator>` and the other is `MyIterator<int>::Impl<std::vector<int>::iterator>`?

Comment: @aschepler I think the any_iterator documentation is correct: Either you make it safe (by only allowing to compare the same impls, checked using typeid), in which case it's impossible to implement it. Or (possibly only in case you regognized the type-ids to be different) you static_cast one side to the other, in which case you have to assume both iterators have the same underlying layout and would "work" when interpreted as a different type.

Comment: Of course, the latter idea makes the entire thing type-unsafe, so I wouldn't go that way.

Answer (score 4):

While the other answers have pointed that this kind of relationship isn't "built-in" with templates, you should note that it is possible to  build functionality to work with this sort of relationship. For example, [`boost::shared_dynamic_cast` and friends](http://svn.boost.org/svn/boost/trunk/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp) given

```
class A { ... };
class B : public A { ... };
```

let you cast between `boost::shared_ptr<A>` and `boost::shared_ptr<B>`.

Note that if you do go about implementing something like this, you'll have to be careful about the operations that MyIterator supports. For example, using your example of `MyIterator<Base>(std::list<Derived>::iterator)`, you should not have an lvalue version of `operator*()`, eg,

```
  *myIter = someBaseValue;
```

should not compile.

Comment: My iterator example starter-implementation returns lvalues from the dereference operator. I think that's a sensible thing to do.

Comment: The prototypical iterators (pointers) allow sliced assignments (if the base class has public assignment).  I think it's reasonable for the class template to support it and put responsibility to be careful with it onto the programmer.

Comment: Shrug. Maybe the better argument is "avoid mixing inheritance and assignment" instead of preventing it with the iterator class. This example isn't really slicing though, you're assigning a base to a derived, not a derived to a base.

Answer (score 1):

`Foo<Derived>` doesn't inherit `Foo<Base>`, so you can't convert the former to the latter. Also, your assumption is wrong: `dynamic_cast` will fail.

You could create a new object of instance of `Foo<Base>` that copies your `Foo<Derived>` instance, but I guess this is now what you're looking for.